Feeling very faint after a long ride
I am a novice distance rider here in the Phoenix area, especially along the AZ Canal. I'm sure part of what I'm experiencing is heat related, which is why I try to ride early in the morning. I can do anywhere from 15 - 33 miles (24 to 53 km) at a speed 14 & 16 mph (around 25 kmh) average. It seems as I near the end of my ride, I start feeling flushed, faint, light headed, and all seems to start around my waist and midsection. There is usually some labored breathing involved. It also seems my recovery is getting longer and longer.
I'm not climbing serious hills except for at 56th St and Indian School Rd at AZ SRP FALLS. The rest of my ride is gradual uphill, and I'm pedaling at a steady consistent clip. This, whatever it is, is starting to kind of scare me. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What are the conditions when you're riding?  Is there any change when it's cooler?

What is your age, fitness level and recent past activity. Thinking anything from a simple case of "Too hard too soon" through to 'Go directly to doctor, don't pass Go". A doctors visit for a physical might be prudent.

Early morning? Have you eaten beforehand? Fasted rides are a thing, and going from hunched over for a long period to standing up suddenly can lead to dizziness until you're used to it

Breathing more heavily than expected for the effort could also be from fat burning (on a fasted ride), especially if accompanied by thirst

You are riding in Phoenix when it is over 110 outside... I think you can probably give yourself a break in that sense.

If you haven't yet mixed electrolytes into your water bottles, I would try that first following the recommended dosage level.
Electrolytes can help sustain your blood pressure and alleviate light headedness when you have a sudden change of posture.
If you think you drink enough electrolytes, I would follow mattnz recommendation to see a Doctor.
